# sort row's similar columns and put row other items below the sorted row name

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sort rows names and print the corresponding values below them.

text file contains

```
x 1 asd
x 2 asd
x 3 asd
x 4 asd
x 5 asd
x 5 asd
x 7 asd
b 8 axy
b 9 axc
```

output required

```
x 
asd
asd
asd
asd
asd
asd
asd

b
axy
axc
```

Comment: It is not clear if your table always has a single value in the first column and if the second column is always a nice incrementing index.

Comment: I have changed the title, I'm not sure how to explain this. I just need to sort out the similar row names in a file and then put the rest of the items in the next column below it.

Comment: So you want to group by the first column? Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: items in the first column in the above text fie could be the same and corresponding items to these values are different. So I want to print x only one time and whatever in front to the x should be printed below x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```py
with open('infile.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    rows = [row.split() for row in f.readlines()]
    print('rows:'); print(rows)
    column = [rows[0][0]] + [row[-1] for row in rows]
    print('column:'); print(column)
    with open('outfile.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as g:
        for row in column:
            g.write(f'{row}\n')

# check the output file:
with open('outfile.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    print('contents of output file:')
    [print(row.strip('\n')) for row in f.readlines()]
```

Explanation:

- read all lines from the input file and split each into a list of tokens, creating a list of lists named `rows`
- create a list named `column` whose first element is the top left element of `rows`, with the remaining elements coming from the right column of `rows`
- write the contents of `column` to the output file one at a time, each on its own line using `\n` as the line terminator
- read and print the output file to check it contains the desired output (taking care to to strip the final `\n` since `print()` appends its own `\n`)

Output:

```
rows:
[['x', '1', 'asd'], ['x', '2', 'asd'], ['x', '3', 'asd'], ['x', '4', 'asd'], ['x', '5', 'asd'], ['x', '5', 'asd'], ['x', '7', 'asd']]
column:
['x', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd']
contents of output file:
x
asd
asd
asd
asd
asd
asd
asd
```

**UPDATE**: Addressing OP's modified question.

```py
with open('infile.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    rows = [row.split() for row in f.readlines()]
    print('rows:'); print(rows)
    columns = []
    col = []
    iRow = 0
    while iRow < len(rows):
        if iRow == 0 or rows[iRow - 1][0] != rows[iRow][0]:
            if iRow > 0:
                columns.append(col)
            col = [rows[iRow][0]]
        col.append(rows[iRow][-1])
        iRow += 1
    columns.append(col)
    print('columns:'); print(columns)
    
    #column = [rows[0][0]] + [row[-1] for row in rows]
    #print('column:'); print(column)
    with open('outfile.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as g:
        isFirstCol = True
        for column in columns:
            if isFirstCol:
                isFirstCol = False
            else:
                g.write(f'\n')
            for row in column:
                g.write(f'{row}\n')

# check the output file:
with open('outfile.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    print('contents of output file:')
    [print(row.strip('\n')) for row in f.readlines()]
```

Output:

```
rows:
[['x', '1', 'asd'], ['x', '2', 'asd'], ['x', '3', 'asd'], ['x', '4', 'asd'], ['x', '5', 'asd'], ['x', '5', 'asd'], ['x', '7', 'asd'], ['b', '8', 'axy'], ['b', '9', 'axc']]
columns:
[['x', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd'], ['b', 'axy', 'axc']]
contents of output file:
x
asd
asd
asd
asd
asd
asd
asd

b
axy
axc
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working really fine. Just one thing can we do this same if the file has other entires for example ( I have updated the question, could you please take a look? )

Comment: I'm not seeing you update to the question

Comment: edited just now.

Comment: I see you have updated your question significantly. Normally you should ask a new question in such cases. I (and perhaps others on SO) would be happy to help you with the new question, but I have already invested my time into answering your original question, so I will be more likely to help with your new question if you first mark my answer to your original question as accepted (assuming you agree that it did what your first question asked, if not what you intended to ask).

Comment: Feel free to put a link to your new question in the comments here, so I will know that you have asked it, and I will do my best to answer it as well.

Comment: Hello sure bro. I'll post the new question as well. thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72332043/remove-duplicates-from-column-names-and-print-crossponding-items

Answer (score 1):

Use csv reader

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    oldx, newx = '', ''
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '):
        newx = row[0]
        if newx != oldx:
            print(newx)
            oldx = newx
        print(row[-1])
```